# Do I need a local version of Spark when connecting to another spark cluster through sparklyr?

Tags: apache-spark, sparklyr

I have a production R cluster with Rstudio installed. Users are load-balanced onto an R server and write code there. I also have a separate Spark cluster which has 4 nodes. Using sparklyr I can easily connect to my spark cluster via:

```
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect("spark://<my cluster>:7077")
```

The only thing is that I notice is that there is some Spark application usage on the R production server when I do this. I believe this is causing some issues. I have Spark installed on both R production servers and Spark cluster at the same `SPARK_HOME` location of `/var/lib/Spark`.

I would like to avoid having Spark on my R servers completely so that there is no usage related to Spark there. How do I do that with `sparklyr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do need local Spark installation to submit Spark applications. The rest depends on the mode:

- In the client mode driver will run on the same node from which you submit application.
- In the cluster mode, driver will run on the cluster. There will be no local Spark process. This however doesn't support interactive processing.

Comment: what is interactive processing? Is that just with live data?